# AWS IoT mobile application

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub, aws-iot

IoT beginner here... I am looking to build a mobile app to communicate to one of my devices using AWS / Azure IoT. Before start building the app I thought to get advice from experts. Does AWS / Azure IoT has any built-in mobile app which I can reuse or do I need to build app from scratch? I would really appreciate if anybody can share the whole process (Not AWS / Azure IoT communication but the steps to build mobile app for AWS / Azure IoT)

Answer (score -1):

This is really off-topic for SO, however each IoT Provider like Azure and AWS does have it's own quick start guides.

Raspberry Pi 3, running Windows 10 IoT Core OS has some built in support for their IoT Hub integration, if you are familiar with C# its a very easy entry point to IoT in general.
See [Windows 10 Internet of Things](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot)